# Increase the Translate 100 Document Limit

Tags: limit, document, google-translate

When using `C#` to call `BatchTranslateText` of the `Cloud Translation API`, I get an error when trying to translate more than `100` files at a time. Is there a way to increase this limit?

Answer (score 0):

No, because Google Translator API is Paid service if you want more than 100 docs at a time or specific no of translation within a minute, then you have to buy it and believe me its too cheap.

Comment: Thanks. We are paying already. We're still limited to 100 documents though.